# Groovy - How to transfer XML nodes between documents?

Tags: xml, groovy

to the %subj%, I've tried:

```
def xp = new XmlParser();
def testsuite = xp.parseText( "<testsuite/>" );
def testsuite1 = new XmlParser().parse( "testsuite.xml" );
testsuite1.testcase.each {
  testsuite.append( it );
}
```

But this gives me an exception:

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.Node.append() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.util.Node) values: {testcase ..., ... }

Despite of: http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Node.html
 says: `boolean append(Node child)`

So, how do I copy/move nodes between documents? (In a Groovy way - not using W3D DOM / JDOM...)

Thanks,
Ondra

Comment: Note for myself - kpiwko's solution was in [calling the API differently](http://git.app.eng.bos.redhat.com/jbossqe-mobile.git/diff/sandbox/buildenv/build.gradle?id=60feab865965f468957fcab31e453faa27fad731)

Answer (score 2):

The following works, I guessed as to what the contents of testsuite.xml might look like. It likely that your file is the problem.

```
def ts = "<testsuite/>"
def ts1 = """
<testsuite>
  <testcase>
    <foo>bar</foo>
  </testcase>
  <testcase>
    <foo>baz</foo>
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
""".trim()

def testsuite = new XmlParser().parseText(ts)
def testsuite1 = new XmlParser().parseText(ts1)

testsuite1.testcase.each {
  testsuite.append(it);
}

assert "bar" == testsuite.testcase[0].foo.text()
assert "baz" == testsuite.testcase[1].foo.text()
```

Comment: This really works for you? Not for me... still the same error.

Comment: $ groovy -version
Groovy Version:  JVM: 14.0-b16
$ groovy xmlText.gy
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.Node.append() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.util.Node) values: {testcase[attributes={}; value=[foo[attributes={}; value=[bar]]]]}
        at xmlText$_run_closure1.doCall(xmlText.gy:17)
        at xmlText.run(xmlText.gy:16)
        at xmlText.main(xmlText.gy)

Comment: Groovy 1.6.4, Linux, Sun JDK 1.6

Comment: John's code works for me - Groovy 1.6.3, Windows XP, Sun JDK 1.6.0_16

Comment: I tried the code I posted using Groovy 1.6.4/Sun JDK 1.6.0_14 on both Linux (Ubuntu 9.04 x64) and Windows (Vista x64).  I also tried it on the online Groovy Console http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/ and it works there too.

Comment: Your groovy -version strings looks odd, mine is "Groovy Version: 1.6.4 JVM: 1.6.0_14".  Sure you don't have an older groovy version in your path?